# dataset does not appear in my R package

Tags: r, devtools

I want to include a dataset in a package I'm building.  I followed all the steps in this [primer](http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/data.html).

- Create a data subdirectory and save the dataset as `myPackage/data/this_dataset.Rdata`
- Create a `.R` file with `Roxygen2` comments, saved as `myPackage/R/this_dataset-data.R`
- Include the line `LazyData: true` in the `DESCRIPTION` file.

Then I install it:

```
> library("devtools")
> setwd("D:/workspace/myPackage")
> install()
Installing aPackage
Skipping 1 package ahead of CRAN: data.table
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "D:/workspace/myPackage" --library="C:/Users/aUser/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'aPackage' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (aPackage)

Reloading installed aPackage
```

So it looks like it figured out that there are datasets.

But then I can't get the dataset to load.  `print(this_dataset)` should work with lazy loading but returns "object not found" error.  `data(this_dataset)` returns "data set not found."  I do: `data(package='aPackage')` and get `no data sets found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does the NAMESPACE file look like?

Comment: @drmariod all the NAMESPACE file contains is `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` -- Maybe that is making my dataset fail since its name contains an underscore?

Comment: @drmariod I tried changing the NAMESPACE to a different export pattern like `exportPattern("^[^\\.]")` mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13436284/2573061) but no difference

Comment: the namespace doesnt have anything to do with data sets.. silly question but you are _building_ the package before you install it, correct?

Comment: How does sour `.R` file for the data look like? Does it has `@docType data`, `@keywords datasets`, `@format A data frame with 95 rows and 32 variables` and `@name proteinGroups` as parameters (not sure if you need them all but this is what I set)? And I normally add a `NULL` after the comment block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it mattered, but changing the file name from `myPackage/data/this_dataset.Rdata` to `myPackage/data/this_dataset.RData` (note difference in capitalization of file extension) seems to have made the difference.